# Asp custom validator is not working in IE-11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-2.0

I am migrating my application from IE 9 to IE 11 with compatibility edge mode.
the asp custom validator and required field validator is not working in IE 11, but page.isValid() always returns true. but it works fine in IE 9.

Sample Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboType" onChange="fnInvalid(this,'hidTypeValid');getSelectedValue('cboType','hidliab');changeOptions(document.forms[0].hidliab,document.forms[0].cmbLiability,document.forms[0].hid_liab,document.forms[0].HIDSERLIAB);" runat="server" name="cbotype"AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="VreqvalidateType" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="cboType" ErrorMessage="-Case Type should not be blank" InitialValue="Choose"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator ClientValidationFunction="fnInvalidSelection" ID="VcustTypeValid"
runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="cboType" ErrorMessage="-Case Type should have valid selection."></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator ClientValidationFunction="fnTypeFileClass" ID="VcusTypeFile" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="cboType" ErrorMessage="- Case File Classification should not be empty."></asp:CustomValidator>

 <asp:CustomValidator Enabled="false"ClientValidationFunction="fnTypeCaseHandler"ID="VcusTypeCaseHandler" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="cboType"ErrorMessage="- Case Handler 1  should not be empty."></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Javascript:

```
<pre lang="C#">function fnTypeCaseHandler(sender,args)
    {
    var s = args.Value;
    args.IsValid = true;
        if (s!="K")
        {
        var handler1= document.frmCaseDetails.cmbHandler1.value;
        if (handler1 =="Choose")
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        }
    return args.IsValid;
    }

function fnTypeFileClass(sender,args)
    {
    var s = args.Value;
    args.IsValid = true;
        if (s!="K")
        {
        var file = document.frmCaseDetails.cmbFileClass.value;
        if (file =="Choose")
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        }
    return args.IsValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of an IE-11 Issue we have made`<meta>` tag with IE-11 compatibility in header section of page its worked well.